# Using selenium to log into a webpage error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm learning to automate with python and I am writing a simple code to open a website and log in. The login credentials have been changed. Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

myArcadiaUsername = "randomusername"
myArcadiaPassword = "randompassword"


url = "https://arcadia-ccc-idp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=24eomia4acadsscdt2jac0davr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fccc.arcadiaanalytics.com%2Fomniauth%2Fcognito%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope%5B%5D=openid&scope%5B%5D=email&scope%5B%5D=profile&state=89c98f8f8b105d27e43f5988e6c15b7efb880a572c5681e2"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get(url)

def login(url,usernameId, username, passwordId, password, submit_buttonId):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("signInFormUsername").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("signInFormPassword").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_name("signInFormPassword").click()

print("logged in successfully")
```

**Here's the error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\Python Projects\Arcadia Desktop Login\LoginArcadia.py", line 9, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in **init**
super(WebDriver, self).**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 90, in **init**
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the chrome driver to path or specify the path to the chromedriver when you call the webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Thank You! I specified the path to chrome driver and I received a different error. Here: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: this might be a problem with the path, what did you enter?

could you post the entire stack trace